# Failed inserting data

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I really don't know where is the problem.
my variables:

```
String notes = hNotes.getText();
Double resTot = Double.parseDouble(hRes.getText());
Double reakTot = Double.parseDouble(hReak.getText());
```

here is the buttonActions:

```
try {            
        String que = "insert into result(notes,resistance,reactant) values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(que, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, notes);
        ps.setDouble(2, resTot);
        ps.setDouble(3, reakTot);

        ps.executeUpdate(); //this code is failed to execute
        ps.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Success..!!","Info Message",1);

    } catch (SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Failed..!!","Error Message",0);
    } finally{
        loadData();
    }
```

When I hit the button, it always give me failed result.
and here is my table structure:

```
id, int(11) --> autoincrement
notes, varchar(20), not null
resistance, double, not null
reactant, double, not null
```

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: no error message, It just execute the SQLException

Comment: Do you need a space `result(notes . .), -- result (notes . .) ?

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I just updated the table structure.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the data - considering the "NOT NULL"?   Do you need to add the schema name before the table name?

Comment: yeah, I got all data.

Comment: Thanks for the table structure. Can you please write `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block and update the output?